# jQuery Tools & Colorbox | Styling change on Exit Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox, jquery-tools

http://www.44db.com/demo/carousel_photos/

I'm facing the following behavior. Click on an image, colorbox opens fine! When closing colorbox either by clicking outside the overlay or by clicking on the 'x' close button then on the carousel items if you notice the div items moves a little bit on the left. This happens only the first time and stays like that.

It looks like it is a css thing however I cannot find it. It looks like there are no 'overlapping' stylesheet classes and I have wrapped the carousel in a div to seperate it
from the colorbox items with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found what is being changed but not how to fix it.

If you check $(".items").position() you will notice that after the colorbox is closed the left value is set to -10.

So, something is definitely being changed, not just a browser rendering issue. I suggest you find the function that is called when the colorbox is called and debug to find where it recalculates the position of $(".items"). This is definitely a bug.

Comment: thank you very much!!!
I will try and use an important css value and see how that goes for the time. Then I'll try and debug.
Thanks

Comment: If you make your code available somewhere for me to download I can go over it and find it for you. As it stands I don't have the time to download everything and set everything up. Send me a link to a .zip and I'll have a look.